# Guava function toByteArray() returning null?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, guava

Here's my code snippet:

```
File file = new File("encryptedImageFileName");
byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
try
{
    encryptedBytes = Files.toByteArray(file);
}
catch (Exception e)
{}
```

Here's an image of the two variables **encryptedBytes** and **file** after I stepped through with the debugger,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nJgs.png

I'm almost certain that all of the stuff under **file** means that it in fact found the file, but as you can see **encryptedBytes** is null, so **Files.toByteArray(file)** didn't work... Why did this happen?

**********************************EDIT********************************

Here's my code where I try to write the byte array, is there something wrong with it?

```
FileOutputStream outputStream;
try
{
    outputStream = openFileOutput("encryptedImageFileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(encodedByteArrayImage);
    outputStream.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This throws

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: encryptedImageFileName: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The debugger says that **encodedByteArrayImage** has a (non-null) value.

Comment: Louis provides detail in his answer, but it's worth saying: *don't ignore exceptions*. The compiler essentially told you that the i/o operation could fail and made you put it in a try/catch so that you cater for that possibility. When your code didn't work, an exception should have been one of your first debugging thoughts. (Indeed, with some logging in the exception block, there never would have been any mystery at all).  Just a friendly tip for the future ...

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: encryptedImageFileName: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: So there's your answer. It is null because the file doesn't exist, and it doesn't exist because you're trying to create a file in a non-existent directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it,

here's the code to write:

```
try
    {
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().getPath() + "encryptedImageFileName.txt");
        ByteSink sink = Files.asByteSink(file);
        sink.write(encryptedBytes);
    }
catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here's the code to read:

```
encryptedBytes = null;
try
    {
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().getPath() + "encryptedImageFileName.txt");
        ByteSource source = Files.asByteSource(file);
        encryptedBytes= source.read();
    } 
catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After using ByteSink instead of what I was doing before to write, I got a Read-Only error because I was trying to write to root instead of the app directory, I was missing this:

```
this.getFilesDir().getPath() +
```

before the file name (also added a .txt at the end of the name).

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  You can create a `new File` that doesn't actually exist on the filesystem and can't be opened just fine, and then you'll get an `IOException` when you try to read from it, which looks like what's happening here.

Try using `e.printStackTrace()` to find out what exception is being thrown and why.

Comment: Thank you.

Why is it that when I run the app normally, I only get an error (and a stack trace) when it tries to use the null byte array, not inside the catch block? I had to step by step debug to see the exception thrown, is that just how exceptions work?

Comment: Can you tell me if there's a problem here, where I try to write the byte array?


Screenshot (couldn't add code in a comment): http://i.imgur.com/B0WjxcJ.png

Comment: If you're catching the exception, then that's how the exception is getting handled.  I can't tell you issues about your specific debugger, though.